# Can I set the default simulation/experiment to run in AnyLogic?

Tags: anylogic

When I open a model in AnyLogic, if I click the Run button (or press F5) it will run the standard "Simulation" (which usually seems to be called `Simulation: Main`, since Main is the name of our top level agent).

In my project, running  `Simulation: Main` is not useful. There is important setup work performed in a Custom Experiment.

Initially, I have to use the menu to run my Custom Experiment, rather than `Simulation: Main`. From then on, until I close and reopen the project, F5 will run my Custom Experiment.

I would like to make my Custom Experiment the default, so that if I open the project and press F5, it will run that, rather than `Simulation: Main`.

Is there a way to do that?

(The closest I have as a workaround is to include startup code in `Simulation: Main` to check whether the environment is set up as per the Custom Experiment, and if not, to throw an exception to remind myself that I have to run the Custom Experiment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that.

Normally, you don't care in the IDE. For end users, you either export the correct experiment into an App or you send them the direct link to the Cloud experiment to use...

So you gotta get used to doing it manually once at each IDE session